# Laravel 5 - How to bulk insert in a table from fields constructed dynamically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am building a review website using Laravel 5

I have list of review features in a table as below

[image: Database structure for questions]

and using @foreach, i am building a page to submit rating for each features

[image: Blade Template]

Result of template is as shown below

[image: Result]

My problem is, i need to store the result in below table along with review feature id (i.e) id of the question from the first table. I am able to do a bulk insert of the selected values in below table using DB::insert() , but i am not able to get and insert the review feature id for each rating selected.

[image: Result i need in database]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you `return Input::get('rating');` on your controller?

Comment: Hi - it is giving an array of values selected in the select boxes. ["0","0","2","0","0"]. BTW, I used return $request->input('rating');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your form a bit:

```
@foreach($rf as $question)
<li>
    {{ Form::hidden("result[review_feature_id][$rf->id]", $rf->id) }}
    {{ $question->name }}
    {{ Form::select("result[rating][$rf->id]", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</li>
@endforeach
```

Now, in your controller, the result of `Input::get('result')` will be a associate array like this:

```
array(
   [0] => array(
     'review_feature_id' => 3
     'rating' => 0
      )
   [1] => array(
     'review_feature_id' => 2
     'rating' => 1
      )
   ...
)
```

P/S: Please replace the screenshot of your code by a text, so that others can help you easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with slight modification. I will also paste code text instead of screenshot henceforth and thanks for pointing this.